# StaggeredGrid with items spanning the 2 columns

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I need to implement a StaggeredGrid view which looks like this:

[image: layout]

The items will be dynamically added so it must be scrollable (as a whole) and recycle views.

I have seen solutions for classic staggered grid with 2 columns and items of different heights but none of them seem to be able to handle items spanning the 2 columns.

I have read posts about the new RecyclerView which seems to be more flexible but it seems i would have to implement my own LayoutManager for this which looks a bit daunting as i am relatively new to Android.

What do you think would be the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement. I resized the views to occupy the extra space. The logic I used was : Let each block be of fixed height h if any block has its height H such that H%h != 0 then increase the height of the block with the remainder of H%h so that it becomes a multiple of h

eg If you fix the height of each block to be say 10dp if a block has 5 increase it to 10. If a block has 31 increase it to 40 ie make the height a multiple of 10. 
To increase the height you should add an empty view with white backgrount to the view so that it appears to be empty space and not part of your block